# Header size on new user pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

The [new user page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112151/new-user-page-live-on-meta) is live. Rejoice!

However, the headers look odd here:

[Screenshot of my profile http://so.mrozekma.com/unix-new-profile.png](http://so.mrozekma.com/unix-new-profile.png)

The ones with links within them are too big, so they run into the text below them, except for Reputation, which is too small and ends up with a scrollbar. The ones without links appear to be fine. I'm using Chromium on Linux; someone with Firefox confirmed the header size mismatch (although he doesn't see the reputation scrollbar)

Comment: This has been fixed (a couple days ago I think).

Comment: @Mat Ah, indeed. Thanks

Comment: Is the reputation scrollbar still an issue? I can't repro it on either Windows or Mac here. Almost 3 years later... maybe it got fixed?

Comment: @AnnaLear Seems fixed now; the style isn't even the same as that screenshot anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro), or [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)?

[image: perfect alignment]

(Chrome 16.0.912.41 under Debian squeeze)

Comment: The header size is fixed for me now; the reputation scrollbar still isn't (same as your screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

Scrollbar on the "Reputation" heading is still there, and on Chrome for Mac as well.

The issue seems to be the `padding-top: 15px` on `.user-show-new .user-panel #leagueRank a`. That's the same amount of padding used on Stack Overflow. SO has 34-pixel-tall headings, while the unix.se ones are only 27 pixels, so the amount of padding that's good there is too much here (`8px` or a little less would probably be about right).